# CorePlot bar graph with bottomless bars

Tags: iphone, graph, core-plot, bar-chart

I am writing an iPhone app that uses CorePlot for graphing.  Specifically bar graphs.  Is there any way to make a bar graph where the bottoms of the bars extend downward forever (or make it look that way) instead of the bars stopping at the x-axis?

I still need the graph to autofit properly and to allow the user to pan the graph without seeing the bottoms of the bars.  That is why I can't use something like `<CPBarPlot instance>.baseValue=CPDecimalFromString(@"-1e20")`.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can limit the panning ranges on the plot space so that the user never sees values outside the range you set.

```
CPTXYPlotSpace *thePlotSpace = graph.defaultPlotSpace;
thePlotSpace.globalYRange = [CPTPlotRange rangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromDouble(0.0)
                                                     length:CPTDecimalFromDouble(10.0)];
barPlot.baseValue = CPTDecimalFromDouble(-1.0);
```